# Organizing JQuery snippets via js frameworks

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I have a zend framework application with several viewscripts and distributed jquery code which looks awful and is hard to maintenance (no structure, loosely snippets etc.)

Now I want to do a cleanup by centralizing all the application related javascript stuff.

Is there a js framework which helps me to organize the jquery stuff to a central and structured javascript layer? Maybe something like angular.js, backbone.js related? I don't know if these framework are adequate for my problem or just an additional overhead.

Comment: have you looked at http://boilerplatejs.org ?  It is a reference architecture for maintainable complex JS projects. You may use it just with jQuery, or with a MVX library such as Backbone, KnockoutJS etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend You backbone.js because it has no built in databinding, so it has no specific requirements on html code. I can strongly recommends [peepcode tutorial](https://peepcode.com/screencasts/javascript), You will get great bonus into Your learning curve with it.
With backbone You will have great power in decoupling client side layer into model and view, instead of classic jquery events spagetti and You will keep availability of using jquery in places where You will want to keep it.
Iam sure You can have it with the other clientside MVCs too, but think about "two way databinding" frameworks (Angular, knockout,...) which requires html inline data-bind attributes to specify UI behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using requirejs to help manage the js on your site.  It was designed to provide a strict structure for your js.  http://www.requirejs.org/

One of the biggest reasons for using require.js is that it adds  object oriented programming style for javascript.

Comment: This was asked nearly a year ago =P

Comment: that might be.. but if someone finds this via a search there  is a little more info available